# ZIP Archive Becomes Corrupt Only After Upload to FTP From PHP

Tags: php, file-upload, ftp, zip, corruption

**Edit:** this describes my problem exactly, but I can't overcome it with PHP: http://kb.winzip.com/kb/entry/149

I am writing an automated backup script in PHP which makes a backup copy of my website's files and database, and sends these files to a remote FTP site for disaster recovery. My SQL and ZIP files (no pun intended on the My SQL) are generated perfectly on the server, however, my ZIP archive becomes corrupt when it is uploaded to the FTP site.

I downloaded the ZIP file from the server which generated it, and opened it no problem. But no ZIP extraction program seems to be able to open the same file once it is transferred to the FTP site and downloaded from there. I can open my SQL file no problem.

I'm pretty sure the archive is OK, but rather, the fault lies in the transferring of the file:

```
$conn_id = ftp_connect("ftp.example.com");
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, "johnny1", "Re@l1y $tr0nG P@5swOrd!");
$dbBackup = fopen('database-backup.sql', 'r');
$filesBackup = fopen('files-backup.zip', 'r');

if (ftp_fput($conn_id, 'database/backup.sql', $dbBackup, FTP_BINARY) && 
    ftp_fput($conn_id, 'files/backup.zip', $filesBackup, FTP_BINARY)) {
  echo "Done!<br>";
} else {
   echo "Failed";
   exit;
}

ftp_close($conn_id);
fclose($dbBackup);
fclose($filesBackup);
```

Is there anything wrong with the transfer of the ZIP file that you can see from here?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Does viewing the uploaded zip file as text yield any interesting results?

Comment: @arxanas Nope... just starts off like this: PK    '`!A±€Ã<E  m     enable_javascript.phpíXmoÛ6þ ...

Comment: How about writing only one file per FTP connection?

Comment: @arxanas Nay... same result. :(

Comment: Why the -1? Especially without any comments???

Comment: I've tested your code on my Ubuntu system and it worked without problems. Did you already check if the original zip file size and the uploaded zip file size are different?

Comment: @Enzino I've checked and they are the exact same. Could it be the server that receiving the file, or the one sending it? Would there be a better alternative than to use FTP?

Comment: If you try to upload the zip file from the command line, does it work, or do you have the same problem?

Comment: I don't have root access. :( Let me try the interface...

Comment: @Enzino I tried uploading directly via their (I'm assuming) PHP-based interface... breaks it too. What does that say? PHP's fault or the FTP server's?

Comment: This is probably an FTP server problem. Which FTP server are you using? And on which platform, Windows or Linux? Can you try to upload the file on another server, just to see if it works?

Comment: It is Linux->Linux. I'm not sure about the FTP server, as I do not host it. I'll try another and check back.

Comment: @Enzino Yep. It appears to be the server. Upload a non-corrupt version of the same ZIP to another FTP, and got it downloaded with no probs. I you want to add your comment as an answer, I'll accept it. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested your code on my Ubuntu system and it worked without problems.
This is probably an FTP server problem; you should try to upload the file on another FTP server.

Answer (score 0):

You could try opening your zip file in binary mode. [It's recommended](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php).

> For portability, it is strongly recommended that you always use the 'b' flag when opening files with fopen().

```
fopen('files-backup.zip', 'rb');
```

Comment: Sorry. That didn't work. From WinRAR, I get an "unexpected end of archive" error.